# How do I roll back Mac OS X system software updates?

Tags: macos, mac

Turns out that the latest version of Java (6u29) isn't compatible with Microsoft's JDBC driver.  So, our LOB software is failing to start on Macs.  I need to roll it back to a prior version, but have no idea how to do so.

Comment: It's an upstream bug and both Oracle and MS are aware of it.  They're working on it, but it appears that it's not yet been resolved.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2011/11/07/supported-java-versions-november-2011.aspx  For now we just won't be able to support Mac users with this app, they'll have to spin up a VM or something, unless someone can come up with another viable workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No,
[There's no way to undo/rollback any updates to the OS or its applications once updated.](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=787628)

Your only option is to do a system restore/reinstall. Not a pleasant alternative, I know but that's what you're facing.

Click the link above for more information.

Comment: Java is supplied from Apple, so it comes in through the OS X system updater.  I've been able to grab the developer preview of OpenJDK 7 and install that alongside (which doesn't help, since it's also not compatible), but I haven't figured out how to find previous "Apple-blessed" versions so far.

Comment: edited my answer.

Comment: Ugh, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about rolling back updates but if the problem is with a version of Java that is incompatible you may be able to fix it with this method. We use kodak software that won't open if you update java through Mac Software update. To fix it I downloaded Java 1.5 and open it with freeware Pacifist, you then go to your hard drive, System, Library, Frameworks, JavaVM.framework, Versions and delete the two aliases for 1.5 and 1.5.0. Then in Pacifist navigate to Contents, System, Library, Frameworks, JavaVM.framework, Versions then select 1.5 and 1.5.0 right click and Install to Default Location. After that the application opens fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's also a brittle and dangerous hack. If you're dealing with Prinergy Workshop, newer versions don't require jumping through those hoops. They just have other major bugs, like the installer failing on new iMacs.